# Как сделать ответ в виде text при запросе с помощью grequests

Tags: python, парсер, post, асинхронность, asyncio

Код:

```
import grequests
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from openpyxl import Workbook
import time

start_time = time.time()
ua = UserAgent()
cookies = {
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'i1gip0fre5uzl4iqlkubv1cp',
    'SLG_G_WPT_TO': 'ru',
    'SLG_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp': '1',
    'SLG_wptGlobTipTmp': '1',
    'ICusrcartgd': 'be6d8ad2-c52e-49b8-83b2-f384a9feaa60',
    'IWusrsesckgd': 'jojhbQMjYWEdV9ohRKijJKalgxKEvPEPzVqoH/F2376n50ziaNRcMA==',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'catalog.aquamarine.kz',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Opera GX";v="85"',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': ua.random,
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'origin': 'https://catalog.aquamarine.kz',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://catalog.aquamarine.kz/catalog/index.aspx',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=i1gip0fre5uzl4iqlkubv1cp; SLG_G_WPT_TO=ru; SLG_GWPT_Show_Hide_tmp=1; SLG_wptGlobTipTmp=1; ICusrcartgd=be6d8ad2-c52e-49b8-83b2-f384a9feaa60; IWusrsesckgd=jojhbQMjYWEdV9ohRKijJKalgxKEvPEPzVqoH/F2376n50ziaNRcMA==',
}

data = {
    'msearch': '',
}
def get_free_proxies():
    url = "https://free-proxy-list.net/"
    # получаем ответ HTTP и создаем объект soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")
    proxies = []
    for row in soup.find("table", class_='table').find_all("tr"):
        tds = row.find_all("td")
        try:
            ip = tds[0].text.strip()
            port = tds[1].text.strip()
            host = f"{ip}:{port}"
            proxies.append(host)
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return proxies
free_proxies = get_free_proxies()


sites = []
for page in range(1,287):
    sites.append(f'https://catalog.aquamarine.kz/catalog/products.ashx?rnd=536811965&q=&spec=&mip=317&map=7777%20777&mippg=161&mappg=5466%20222&miw=0.14&maw=137.74&miq=1&maq=241&miprcs=999999.999&maprcs=0&page={page}&sort=art-down&view=2&spc=1,&brid=7')


response = (grequests.post(url, cookies=cookies, data=data, headers=headers, proxies = free_proxies) for url in sites)

a = grequests.map(response)
for i in a:
    print(i.text)

print(f'Время выполнения: {time.time() - start_time} секунд')
```

Мне нужно получить ответ в виде text. И да я понимаю что grequests.map вернёт просто статус, но я не знаю как тогда делать.

Comment: Я посмотрел какой статус кода отправляет он, и увидел в конце None много раз. Как я понял скорее всего сайт блокирует что-то

Answer (score 0):

Прокси не работают, нужно их просто убрать

Comment: у grequests.post параметр proxies принимает словарь, а не список. И не факт что на free-proxy-list.net окажутся рабочие прокси.

Comment: Желательно также подробнее написать для тех, кто в будущем столкнётся с данной проблемой, как нужно убрать прокси или что-то в этом роде. Ну и ещё ответ отметьте как верный, если он Вам помог :)